# Insert or Update SQL Table with DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Firstly, I can't use any stored procedures or views.
I know this may seem counter-productive, but those aren't my rules.

I have a `DataTable`, filled with data. It has a replicated structure to my SQL table.

`ID - NAME`

The SQL table currently has a bit of data, but I need to now update it with all the data of my `DataTable`. It needs to UPDATE the SQl Table if the ID's match, or ADD to the list where it's unique.

Is there any way to simply do this only in my WinForm Application?

So far, I have:

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", cmboTableOne.SelectedItem), sqlConn);
            using (new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter))
            {
                try
                {
                    adapter.Fill(DtPrimary);
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    adapter.Update(DtPrimary);
                    sqlConn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception es)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(es.Message, @"SQL Connection", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
            }
```

DataTable:

```
        DataTable dtPrimary = new DataTable();

        dtPrimary.Columns.Add("pv_id");
        dtPrimary.Columns.Add("pv_name");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> valuePair in primaryList)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dtPrimary.NewRow();

            dataRow["pv_id"] = valuePair.Key;
            dataRow["pv_name"] = valuePair.Value;

            dtPrimary.Rows.Add(dataRow);
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ice_provinces](
    [pv_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [pv_name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ice_provinces] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [pv_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Your current code should do the trick. Is it failin with an error, or failing silently? Is this ASP.NET?

Comment: @Renan, it is currently just adding the values to the end of the previous table. - Yes, i can use linq

Comment: Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awzk4kc1.aspx, you need to specify at least the other sql statement for updating data, including the where clause, by which a record is uniquely identified.

Comment: @KaiHartmann no you don't: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx

Comment: @NewAmbition my best guess is that the ID column in your database is not marked as a primary key. Can you check that?

Comment: Ok, then might be, that you haven't set a primary key in your datatable? Could you show the creation of the datatable?

Comment: @Renan Primary key is there

Comment: @KaiHartmann - No, I havent set the PK of the datatable :| Updating the post

Comment: I meant in the database, not in the `DataTable`. The primarey keys of the `DataTable` will be set by the data adapter automatically if they exist in the underlying database.

Comment: @Renan Post updated. The SQL Table has got a PK

Comment: Use a stored procedure with a table-valued parameter. Then you can pass your DataTable in as a set instead of messing with all this ugly looping nonsense.

Comment: @AaronBertrand OP cannot use any stored procedures.

@NewAmbition for insert you can use SqlBulkCopy (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.90).aspx) it's `WriteToServer` method takes DataTable as a parameter

Comment: Can you set the PrimaryKey of your DataTable, to see if it might help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey.aspx Also the SqlCommandBuilder has a method called GetUpdateCommand() which returns the SqlCommand to be executed. Can you give the CommandText it holds? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfbedfwf.aspx

Comment: @KaiHartmann - I'll update the post with that :)

Comment: @KaiHartmann - I've set the primary key. The values dont duplicate anymore, although they DONT update when there is a change in the name. The `UpdateCommand` is `null`

Comment: I tried for over an hour now, but didn't get it done. All I was able to do, was updating records after they were loaded by Fill().

Comment: @KaiHartmann this isnt going well :/ Looks like the brute force method below might be the only option.

Comment: Or you do this: 1. Load data from db by Fill() to datatable 2. update the records in the datatable or create new ones (the logic you would have to implement manually by using the primary key) 3. use adapter.Update()

Comment: @KaiHartmann will it not be useful to set the select, update and delete commands for the adapter? will that work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34047/discussion-between-newambition-and-kai-hartmann)

Answer (score 3):

Since you're going update existing values and insert new ones from datatable that has ALL the data anyway I think the following approach might work best for you:

1. Delete all existing data from the SQL Table (you can use TSQL [TRUNCATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) statement for speed and efficiency
2. Use ADO.NET `SqlBulcCopy` class to bulk insert data from ADO.NET table to SQL table using [WriteToServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) method.

No views or stored procedures involved, just pure TSQL and .NET code.

Comment: Easy to program but may not scale very well. If there aren't too many records ever, this should work fine.

Comment: @MichaelTodd true, but I beleive TRUNCATE/Bulk copy combination should hold well for hundreds of thousands of records. But it shouldn't even come to this since OP keeps all data in in-memory DataTable and (hopefully) that shouldn't be much.

Comment: That is a very inelegant, brute forcing solution.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Heh. +1 for your pragmatism.

Comment: @MichaelTodd - The maximum entries is about 1500..Will this solution a go :)

Comment: @NewAmbition Please mark as answer if the solution worked for you.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I had been working with another assignment, and hadn't yet gotten the chance to test this. Will mark it as soon as I have :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my try on this, by which I was able to at least update the records in the database. It differs from your solution so far, that it applies values to the DataTable after Fill() has been executed. You would have to search manually in the DataTable if there are records you have to update, that's the drawback.
Another thing is, I realized, that DataTable does not inherit the table schema from database, if you haven't set MissingSchemaAction properly.

So here is the example code (complete ConsoleApplication):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace SQLCommandBuilder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder ConnStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            ConnStringBuilder.DataSource = @"(local)\SQLEXPRESS";
            ConnStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = "TestUndSpiel";
            ConnStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnStringBuilder.ConnectionString);

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", "ice_provinces"), sqlConn);
            adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;   // needs to be set to apply table schema from db to datatable

            using (new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter))
            {
                try
                {
                    DataTable dtPrimary = new DataTable();                                   

                    adapter.Fill(dtPrimary);

                    // this would be a record you identified as to update:
                    dtPrimary.Rows[1]["pv_name"] = "value";

                    sqlConn.Open();
                    adapter.Update(dtPrimary);
                    sqlConn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception es)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(es.Message);
                    Console.Read();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```